# How to Show Author image and url in WordPress plugin directory?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I just added a plugin(My-auction-creator) in to WordPress Plugin directory. But sadly when I open the plugin URL the author image is not showing nor the url is linked.

So anyone can help me to show my image and url there? 
Below the screenshot: 
[image]

Here is the link : https://wordpress.org/plugins/my-auction-creator/

Answer (score 1):

You will need to login to your account at WordPress.org ... if you have one. If you do not have one you need to register.

After that you can edit your profile at https://profiles.wordpress.org/username/ where username is your wordpress.org user name.

Sometimes it take a little while for them to get everything updated. Have they approved your plug-in also?

Comment: ..yes they approved.Actually I have give a wrong username.Now hopefully it going to work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use SVN to update the [`readme.txt`](http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/my-auction-creator/trunk/readme.txt) file which is located in the `/trunk`

**Your current code:**

```
=== My Auction Creator ===
Contributors: Suyog Computech Pvt Ltd
```

**Update line 2** to insert your wp.org account's username rather than the full name:

```
=== My Auction Creator ===
Contributors: username
```

Refresh the page and you'll see a linked avatar and your name as the plugin author, plus a plug-in developer badge in your WP profile.

Enjoy !

Comment: Thanks man.I will go for it after a lil changes in Plugin. @samuel

Comment: You're welcome. I had the same issue last couple days when I uploaded my first plugin. it should work :)

Comment: :) BTW are u on any chatting platform? I need some help 
my twitter username = @iamsumankalyan

Comment: Do people chat on twitter ? Facebook perhaps, tough I am not a fan of them. fb.me/univ.soldier honoring your request :)

Comment: Yeah right.But there is no option to send you a request there in FB. But I have started following you there and sent a message.Have you got any notification?

Comment: sure did. I always keep an eye on my junk folder ;)